# How to make a flat button with rich text formating with Qt4?

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4, richtext, qpushbutton

I would like to create flat buttons displaying rich text and images.
For instance a button should be able to display:

`|¯¯¯¯¯¯|` **Title of Button** `¯¯¯¯|`
`| ICON |` *Description of button* `|`
`|_____̣̣_|___________________|`

I've been playing around with Qt4 and I couldn't find an easy way to produce such a button. Adding a QLabel as a child of a QPushButton does not work properly (the text is not aligned properly and the button does not respect the size of the label's content).

Is there a way to produce a simple flat button that can handle rich text and images as its content? Can I create a button from a QLabel perhaps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qpushbutton.html), you can see that QPushButton doesn't accept child widgets.

So you will have to write your own widget. `QLabel` is a good start. Give it the same border and color that a `QButton` would get (the documentation of the `flat` property of the `QPushButton` should help).

And you'll need to implement `mousePressEvent` plus add the necessary button slots. A good idea is probably to look into the source code of `QAbstractButton` to see how it's implemented.